# rsync not copying files when using --include flag

Tags: rsync

I have the following files:

```
1/2/abc.txt
1/2/def.txt
1/1/abc.txt
2/1/abc.txt
2/2/def.txt
3/1/hij.txt
```

I'd like to copy all `abc.txt` files and preserve the directory tree. I tried the following command:

`rsync -R -P -a -m --include='*/*/abc.txt' remote@server:/target/directory`

but this doesn't copy any files. Any ideas? Would be much appreciated.

Br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rsync -R -P -a -m --include='*/' --include='abc.txt' --exclude='*' source/ remote@server:/target/directory`, where the added `source/` is the source parent directory.

It's still better to specify the actual path to the source parent directory (ether relative or absolute) like `source/` or `/full/path/to/source`. The `-a` option implies `-r` which recurses the subdirectories. It's much better than relying on the shell glob `*` which can expand to multiple other directories under the current working directory and yield unexpected outcomes. You were confused by how `rsync` didn't complain when there is only a target directory and no source directory. This is so that it can support uses cases of the `shopt -s nullglob` where the `*` expands to nothing. But if you only add the source directory, it not only copies the wanted files but other files as well.

[`rsync`'s include syntax is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111793/10477326). You need to add an `--exclude='*'` after your `--include='*/*/abc.txt'` to get it to copy only the files you want. But that causes nothing to be copied because the directories are excluded, so you need to fix that with `--include='*/'`. Empty directories are correctly excluded because you have `-m`.

A shorter version of the above command is `rsync -RPamf '+ abc.txt' -f 'H,! */' source/ remote@server:/target/directory`.

Comment: @Raffa I'm testing locally with `rsync -R -P -a -m --include='*/' --include='*/*/abc.txt' --exclude='*' src/ dst`. For some reason It ends up as `dst/src/1/1/abc.txt` no matter how many times I add or remove `/`'s. The asker probably wants `dst/1/1/abc.txt`

Comment: ... Sorry I missed the last part of your above comment but, the asker seems to want exactly that and that's why they specified `-R` **r**elative paths ... If that is not desired, then `-R` shouldn't be used.